# How to create a dictionary with key as a subclass of NSObject and values as an array? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, data-structures

I want to create a dictionary where keys can be any subclass of `NSObject` and value is an array of `NSObject` subclass.

I tried:

```
class ABC: NSObject {
    var a: Int? = 0

    convenience init(a: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.a = a
    }
}

class XYZ: NSObject {
    var b: String? = "just checking"
    var objOfABC: ABC?

    convenience init(b: String, obj: ABC) {
        self.init()
        self.b = b
        self.objOfABC = obj
    }
}

let arr = [ XYZ(b: "str1", obj: ABC(a: 1)),
            XYZ(b: "str2", obj: ABC(a: 2)),
            XYZ(b: "str4", obj: ABC(a: 1)),
            XYZ(b: "str7", obj: ABC(a: 3)),
            XYZ(b: "str0", obj: ABC(a: 1)),
            XYZ(b: "str9", obj: ABC(a: 2)),
          ]


var dictionary: [ABC: [XYZ]] = [:]

for obj in arr {
    dictionary[obj.objOfABC ?? ABC()]?.append(obj)
}

for obj in dictionary {
    print(obj.key.debugDescription)
    print(obj.value.debugDescription)
}
```

The `dictionary` is nil.

Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but why is `ABC` and `XYZ` a subclass of `NSObject` and not a plain old `struct`?

Comment: @rmaddy I am working with some very old code and didn't got any time to change it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary starts out empty. So every call to `dictionary[someKey]` will return `nil`. This leads to `append(obj)` never being called and the dictionary remains empty.

Provide a default when accessing the keys:

```
dictionary[obj.objOfABC ?? ABC(), default: []].append(obj)
```

Comment: now the dictionary is getting filled but for every somehow the `keys` are getting repeated and the objects of `XYZ` are not getting appended. Is it because of the `Hash value` of every `ABC` objects are different?

Comment: Since `ABC` is being used as a dictionary key, it needs to have a proper conformance to `Hashable` (and `Equatable`)`.